# Multiplication with zero

Tags: performance-tuning

So I have a function $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ that I want to evaluate on a large discrete set $\Lambda$ expressed as a list. I have that $g$ is complicated and takes time to evaluate at each point in the list, but $h$ is very simple and is indeed, only non-zero for a small number of terms. I am currently using the `Map` function to evaluate the function $f$ on $\Lambda$, i.e. as `Map[g(#)*h(#) &, L]`, where `L` corresponds to $\Lambda$.

Currently, this takes a long time since Map evaluates $g(x)$ over all points in the set even for values where $h(x)=0$ thus deeming $g(x)h(x) = 0$. Although, since $h(x)$ is zero for most $x$, it doesn't really need to compute $g(x)$ if $h(x)=0$.

I was wondering if there is a way to tell Mathematica that for $a*b$, if either $a$ or $b$ is equal to zero, then to set $a*b=0$, as to save on computation time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your data, you may define a tolerance `eps` and use the following function `F` instead:

```
eps = 100 $MachineEpsilon;
F = With[{val = h[#]},
    If[Abs[val] > eps, g[#] val, 0]
    ] &;
Map[F, L]
```

Comment: adding tolerance is a nice idea.

Comment: Well, not a very creative one if one works with floating point data everyday... ;)

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks, that's a good point! I corrected this.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this works:

```
g[x_] := {Pause[1]; x RandomReal[]}
f[x_] := If[x < 5, 0, x]
Map[With[{x = #, fe = f[#]}, If[fe == 0, 0, g[x] fe]] &, Range@10] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.02807, {0, 0, 0, 0, {11.9397}, {18.9161}, {14.929}, {28.8704}, {15.9467}, {11.3731}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing Henrik's thresholding idea, here's a sparse array approach:

```
SeedRandom[0];
lambda = RandomReal[{-400, 2}, 1000];
h = Exp;
g = Sin;
tol = 10^-10;

res = SparseArray[Threshold[h@lambda, tol], Automatic, 0.];
With[{nzp = Flatten@ res@ "NonzeroPositions"},
  res[[nzp]] *= g[lambda[[nzp]]]
  ];
res
```

The default tolerance is `10^-10`, but I included `tol` so that it could be adjusted to each particular case.

Another way, using `Map` for `g` and `h` in case they're not listable:

```
res2 = With[{hvals = 
    SparseArray[Threshold[h /@ lambda, tol], Automatic, 0.]},
  With[{nzp = hvals@"NonzeroPositions"},
   hvals*
    SparseArray[nzp -> g /@ Extract[lambda, nzp], Dimensions@hvals, 0.]
   ]]

res2 == res
(*  True  *)
```